# how to read data stored in a wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a wordpress plugin (broadstreet) which is a company directory and has list of companies. But I want to display in different style to match the rest of the website. Now all the company details are stored in the plugin. Is it possible for me to read the data stored in the plugin and display in a page and publish the same using wordpress? If so how?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, In this case, what I do is create a custom template page. For that you can go to theme you are refering and make a copy of page.php file and rename it. let's say it is directory-page.php.

Next go to admini panel and create a new menu item and set it is template to derectory-page.

Now you can open it and customise as you expect it.

```
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php //get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php// comments_template( '', true ); ?>


            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>



        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you want to remove  the blog content and call your directry displaying method.
simply, comment out

```
<?php //get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<?php// comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php echo call_directory_display();?>
```

Now you have to implement `call_directory_display()` method in your plugin to show content in derectory-page.

If you have any questions ask in comments.